# Why is a 10bp picture environment not 10bp?

Tags: lengths

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\picwidth}

\setlength{\unitlength}{1bp}
\settowidth{\picwidth}{\begin{picture}(10,10)\end{picture}}
\typeout{width: \the\picwidth}

\settowidth{\picwidth}{\rule{10bp}{0pt}}
\typeout{width: \the\picwidth}

\end{document}
```

Output in the log:

```
width: 10.03738pt
width: 10.03749pt
```

I'm expecting the two lines to be the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is due to rounding errors. You can clearly see it if you convert the lengths to integer numbers, which shows the thing TeX core actually stores:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\newlength\lena
\newlength\lenb
\newlength\lenc

\setlength{\lena}{1bp}     % 1bp
\setlength{\lenb}{10\lena} % 10*1bp
\setlength{\lenc}{10bp}    % 10bp

\typeout{a: \the\lena} % 1.00374pt
\typeout{b: \the\lenb} % 10.03738pt
\typeout{c: \the\lenc} % 10.03749pt

\typeout{a: \number\lena} % 65781
\typeout{b: \number\lenb} % 657810
\typeout{c: \number\lenc} % 657817

\end{document}
```

Comment: @tochecz ... and `\numexpr \lena\relax` works too, if you need the value (as an integral number of `sp`'s) in an `\ifnum` test (but to get its explicit representation, one again needs a prefix then, either `\the` or `\number` which both give now the same thing).

Answer (score 12):

To add a little to [tochecz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/11002/tohecz)'s [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/157232/4686): in terms of the smallest dimension unit manipulated by TeX, the `sp`, `1/65536` of a `pt`, a dimension with `d` `bp` units has exact value `(1644544/25)*d` `sp` units. TeX will truncate this to an integer number of sp units. When you multiply by `10` a dimension you actually multiply by `10` its representation as an integral number of `sp` units. When you however express directly a dimension as for example `10bp` then  `floor((1644544/25)*10)` is evaluated.

Thus `1bp` is `floor(1644544/25)`, that is `65781` `sp` units. Then `10*1bp` is `657810` `sp` units.

But `10bp` is `floor(16445440/25)=657817` `sp` units.

And `100bp` is `floor(164454400/25)=6578176` `sp` units (hence exactly represented). The only exactly represented dimensions expressed as an integral number of `bp` units are those multiple of `25bp`.

Answer (score 9):

The reason for the differences has been explained elsewhere. If it's critical that the dimension is as exact as possible, you can load the `picture` package that allows one to express dimensions with their unit of measure in the `picture` environment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{picture}
\begin{document}

\newlength{\picwidth}

\settowidth{\picwidth}{\begin{picture}(10bp,10bp)\end{picture}}
\typeout{width: \the\picwidth}

\settowidth{\picwidth}{\rule{10bp}{0pt}}
\typeout{width: \the\picwidth}

\end{document}
```

The output on the terminal is

```
width: 10.03749pt
width: 10.03749pt
```

Comment: Surprisingly, the original picture environment accepts only integers, (dimensions being then multiple of `\unitlength`) but the primitive `\number` is, to the best of my knowledge, nowhere mentioned in Lamport's book although it is very convenient when one sets `\unitlength` to be `1sp`.

Comment: @jfbu It's good `\number` is not mentioned, as it has a syntax foreign to LaTeX.

Comment: My feeling is that LaTeX's syntax is not that perfect that it should forbid using TeX's primitives! what then about `\numexpr` and `\dimexpr`? (from e-TeX)

Comment: @jfbu `\numexpr` and `\dimexpr` came well after Lamport's manual.

Comment: yes, my point: at the time of Lamport's manual, `\number` was the only way to expandably get the exact value of a dimension. Furthermore, the `picture` environment required integers, but `\the` on a dimension gives a decimal number of `pt`'s.